# Alternating Series Problem Showing $a_n$ is Decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

We are given the following series and we must examine it for convergence
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n - 1}\frac{\ln\left(n\right)}{3n + 2}}.
$$
The sequence $a_n = \frac{\ln\left(n\right)}{3n + 2}$ is obviously positive and approaching  $0$ as $n$ is approaching $\infty$, but I can't prove that its decreasing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried showing its derivative is $<0$ for all $x>M$ for some positive $M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n$ is not decreasing since $a_2 >a_1$ but  it is eventually decreasing. Convergence of a series  does not change if you omit first few terms so it is enough to show that $a_{n+1} <a_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.  Let $f(x)=\frac {\ln x} {3x+2}$. Then $f'(x) <0$ translates to $3+\frac 2  x <3 \ln x$ or $e^{3+\frac 2  x} < x^{3}$. For $x >4$ note that $e^{3+\frac 2  x}<e^{3.5} <4^{3}<x^{3}$.

Comment: Great, I checked it and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference of consecutive terms:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=(3n+5)\ln(n+1)-(3n+2)\ln n=(3n+2)\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)-3\ln n.$$
Now observe that the first term tends to $3$ since
$$\ln n=(3n+2)\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)\sim_\infty 3n\cdot\frac 1n=3.$$
Therefore the first term is bounded, and $\;a_{n+1}-a_n \to -\infty$, so that it is ultimately negative.